# Add string pattern from values to colnames

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe like this, with more ages and more nutritional informations/ column. The unit stays the same for each column, but differs for different nutritional informations.

```
age<-c(1,2,3,4)
energy<-c("2.3 MJ/day", "2.5 MJ/day", "2.9 MJ/day", NA) 
df<-data.frame(age,energy)

| age   | energy    |
| ----- |---------- |
| 1     |2.3 MJ/day |
| 2     |2.5 MJ/day |
| 3     |2.9 MJ/day |
| 4     |NA         |
```

In the end I want to add the non digit (but excl. ".") part of the values (so the Units) to the Header of the column, delete it from the values and convert them to numerics.

```
| age   | energy MJ/day|
| ----- |--------------|
| 1     |2.3           |
| 2     |2.5           |
| 3     |2.9           |
| 4     |NA            |
```

There are a couple of ways to do that by hand:

```
df$energy<-str_sub(df$energy, 1L, 3L)
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "energy"] <- "energy MJ/day"
df$`energy MJ/day`<-as.numeric(df$`energy MJ/day`)
```

As I have a repetition of this structure (more dataframes), I could reuse some vectors. But I still wonder if there is no solution "at site".

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the number always comes before the unit, say:

```
my_string <- "9.6 megawatt"
```

Then you could use `stringr::word` which extracts words from a sentence. THe number would always be the first word, and the unit name the second one.

In your case, that could be used as:

```
age<-c(1,2,3,4)
energy<-c("2.3 MJ/day", "2.5 MJ/day", "2.9 MJ/day", NA) 
df<-data.frame(age,energy)

for (col in names(df)) {
    # find out if there are two words in the first non NA value
    first_val <- df[, c(col)]
    first_val <- first_val[!is.na(first_val)][[1]]
    n_words <- length(stringr::str_split(first_val, pattern = " ")[[1]])
    if (n_words == 2) {
        # Check if the first value is numeric
        value <- as.numeric(stringr::word(first_val, 1))
        if (is.numeric(value)) {
            new_name <- paste(col, stringr::word(first_val, 2), sep = " ")
            col_pos <- which(names(df) == col)
            names(df)[col_pos] <- new_name
            df[, col_pos] <- stringr::word(df[, col_pos], 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is one problem with the outputname- it should be the old colname+the unit. So "energy MJ/day"

Comment: That works good for the example, but by applying it to the dataframe- wired things happen. Getting this warning: ```argument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector; coercingargument is not an atomic vector;  [and so on...]```  in those column which are manipulated (just those with exact 2 Words) i get the values ``` "c(\"2.5"```

Comment: Seems odd! Could you provide a dataframe that manages to reproduce the error? Then I can investigate.

Comment: what I see when I use str() is that in the example here df all columns are factors, while in my df_orig there the columns are simply assigned as character

Comment: I don't understand. When I str() the example, there are no factor columns.

Comment: unfortunatally i wasn`t able to reproduce the error i got. I found an other less reproducable way on that now.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the numeric part from the 'energy' column element, paste with the 'energy' to create a new column with the extracted numeric part from the 'energy' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   transmute(age, !!str_c('energy ', 
     str_remove(first(energy), '.*\\s+')) := readr::parse_number(energy))
```

-output

```
#  age energy MJ/day
#1   1           2.3
#2   2           2.5
#3   3           2.9
#4   4            NA
```

Comment: in my example it doesn't work.: ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `energy MJ/day`.
x is.character(x) is not TRUE
i Input `energy MJ/day` is `readr::parse_number(energy)```

Comment: @Annika May be you have `factor` class.  Can you try `df %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% transmute(..`

Comment: ```Error in mutate.data.frame(.data, ..., .keep = "none") : 
  formal argument ".keep" matched by multiple actual arguments``` And furthermore I don`t understand some things, what is the !! for?

Comment: @Annika The `!!` is for evaluating the string created on the lhs of `:=`.  Usually, with `=`, it won't allow that dynamic creation of column names on the lhs

Comment: @Annika I am not able to understand the error you got.  It should work fine, may be you can try `first(as.character(energy))`